# EF Core 3.1 to 7 changed behavior

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have exitsing EF Core 3.1 code that is working perfectly for inserting data. Here is the code for configuring entities (generated by the scaffolding tool):

```
internal static void ConfigureVehicleEntity(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Vehicle>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(v => v.VehiculeId);
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.HardwareId)
            .HasName("UIX_HardwareID")
            .IsUnique()
            .HasFilter("([HardwareID] IS NOT NULL)");

        entity.HasIndex(e => e.RowVersion)
            .HasName("IX_RowVersion");

        entity.HasIndex(e => e.VehiculeUserId)
            .HasName("UIX_VehiculeUserID")
            .IsUnique()
            .HasFilter("([VehiculeUserID] IS NOT NULL)");

        entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.BoardId, e.CompanyId })
            .HasName("UIX_CompanyIdVehiculeBoardId")
            .IsUnique()
            .HasFilter("([BoardId] IS NOT NULL)");

        entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.GpsBoxType, e.RowEnabled })
            .HasName("IX_RowEnabled");

        entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.VehiculeId, e.Name, e.CompanyId, e.RowEnabled })
            .HasName("IX_CompanyID_RowEnabled");

        entity.Property(e => e.VehiculeId).HasColumnName("VehiculeID").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        entity.Property(e => e.Address).HasMaxLength(250);

        entity.Property(e => e.BoardId)
            .HasColumnName("BoardID")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        entity.Property(e => e.Category).HasMaxLength(128);

        entity.Property(e => e.CompanyId).HasColumnName("CompanyID");

        entity.Property(e => e.CustomId).HasMaxLength(128);

        entity.Property(e => e.DbInsertTime)
            .HasColumnType("datetime")
            .HasDefaultValueSql("(getutcdate())");

        entity.Property(e => e.Description).HasMaxLength(1024);

        entity.Property(e => e.GpsBoxTrackingDelay).HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");

        entity.Property(e => e.HardwareId).HasColumnName("HardwareID");

        entity.Property(e => e.IconId)
            .HasColumnName("IconID")
            .HasDefaultValueSql("((33554432))");

        entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(128);

        entity.Property(e => e.PhoneNumber)
            .HasMaxLength(30)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        entity.Property(e => e.RowEnabled)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");

        entity.Property(e => e.RowVersion)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasConversion(new NumberToBytesConverter<ulong>())
            .IsRowVersion();

        entity.Property(e => e.VehicleUserId).HasColumnName("VehiculeUserID");

        entity.Property(e => e.GpsBoxType).HasColumnName("GpsBoxType");

        entity.Property(e => e.GpsBoxSubType).HasColumnName("GpsBoxSubType");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.GpsBoxTypeNavigation)
            .WithMany(p => p.Vehicule)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.GpsBoxType)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Vehicule_GpsBoxType");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.GpsBox)
            .WithMany(p => p.Vehicule)
            .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.GpsBoxType, d.GpsBoxSubType })
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Vehicule_GpsBoxSubType");
    });
}

internal static void ConfigureRegistrationEntity(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Registration>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.VehiculeId)
            .HasName("PK_RegistrationNew");

        entity.ToTable("Registration", "SafeProtect");

        entity.Property(e => e.VehiculeId)
            .HasColumnName("VehiculeID")
            .ValueGeneratedNever();
        entity.Property(e => e.RegistrationStatus)
            .HasColumnName("RegistrationStatusId")
            .HasDefaultValueSql("((3))")
            .HasConversion(v => (int)v, v => (RegistrationStatus)v);
        entity.Property(e => e.LatestRegistrationStatusChangeDate).HasColumnType("smalldatetime").HasConversion(DateTimeKindUtcConverter);

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Company)
            .WithMany(p => p.Registration)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_RegistrationNew_Company");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Vehicule)
            .WithOne(p => p.Registration)
            .HasForeignKey<Registration>(d => d.VehiculeId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_RegistrationNew_VehiculeID");
    });
}
```

Basically, a Vehicle has a Registration.
But in the database, the foreign key goes from the Registration to the Vehicle table...
Inserting a Vehicle works in EF 3.1.
In code I'm creating a Vehicle and associate a new Registration, saving the graph works fine.

```
Vehicule v = new Vehicule();
v.TrackingState = TrackableEntities.Common.Core.TrackingState.Added;
v.CompanyId = 1;
v.Name = "Test Unitaire";
v.PhoneNumber = "+33614407055";
v.GpsBoxType = 29;
v.Address = "testunitaire@safeprotect.fr";
v.AddressProtocol = 1;

var registration = new Registration();
registration.TrackingState = TrackableEntities.Common.Core.TrackingState.Added;
registration.LatestRegistrationStatusChangeDate = DateTime.Now;
registration.RegistrationStatus = RegistrationStatus.Authorized;
registration.CompanyId = 1;

v.Registration = registration;

// Data layer code not shown here.
```

In EF 7, I have to create Registration first, then the Vehicle in order to be able to insert data :(

Otherwise I have the following error:

```
SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_RegistrationNew_VehiculeID". The conflict occurred in database "RTEGeoloc", table "dbo.Vehicule", column 'VehiculeID'.
```

So, this could be solved by creating the objects the other way around (Registration, the Vehicle), but for complex graphs this could be tricky.

For me this is a major breaking changes. Is that what I think it is ?

**EDIT**:
As requested here are the requested entities.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using MyNameSpace.Common.Data.BusinessObjects.CustomAttributes;

namespace MyNameSpace.Common.Data.BusinessObjects.Models
{
    public partial class Vehicule
    {
        public Vehicule()
        {
            ContextDetail = new HashSet<ContextDetail>();
            ContextDetailData = new HashSet<ContextDetailData>();
            FleetDetail = new HashSet<FleetDetail>();
            GpsPosition = new HashSet<GpsPosition>();
            VehiculeContext = new HashSet<VehiculeContext>();
            VehiculeTemperatureContext = new HashSet<VehiculeTemperatureContext>();
            ActivityHistory = new HashSet<ActivityHistory>();
            LevelOneFleets = new HashSet<Fleet>();
            ReportSubscriptions = new HashSet<ReportSubscription>();

            AdditionalInit();
        }
        public long VehiculeId { get; set; }

        public int CompanyId { get; set; }

        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public long? HardwareId { get; set; }

        public int? VehiculeUserId { get; set; }

        public int GpsBoxType { get; set; }

        public string Category { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int IconId { get; set; }

        public int GpsBoxTrackingDelay { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public int? AddressProtocol { get; set; }

        public string BoardId { get; set; }

        public ulong RowVersion { get; set; }

        public bool RowEnabled { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DbInsertTime { get; set; }

        public string CustomId { get; set; }

        public bool? HasGeoWorker { get; set; }

        public int? GpsBoxSubType { get; set; }

        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

        public virtual GpsBoxSubType GpsBox { get; set; }

        public virtual GpsBoxType GpsBoxTypeNavigation { get; set; }

        public virtual VehiculeGpsBoxInfo VehiculeGpsBoxInfo { get; set; }

        public virtual Registration Registration { get; set; }

        public virtual Device Device { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<FleetDetail> FleetDetail { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ContextDetail> ContextDetail { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<VehiculeContext> VehiculeContext { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<VehiculeTemperatureContext> VehiculeTemperatureContext { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<GpsPosition> GpsPosition { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AlertInstructions> AlertInstructions { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ActivityHistory> ActivityHistory { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ContextDetailData> ContextDetailData { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public virtual ICollection<Fleet> LevelOneFleets { get; set; }

        public bool NotifyUser { get; set; }

        public virtual VehiculeSettings VehiculeSettings { get; set; }

        public string SecuritasContacts { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ReportSubscription> ReportSubscriptions { get; set; }

        public TrackingState TrackingState { get; set; }

        public ICollection<string> ModifiedProperties { get; set; }

        public Guid EntityIdentifier { get; set; }

        partial void AdditionalInit();
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using MyNameSpace.Common.Data.BusinessObjects.CustomAttributes;
using TrackableEntities.Common.Core;

namespace MyNameSpace.Common.Data.BusinessObjects.Models
{
    public partial class Registration : ITrackable, IMergeable
    {
        public long VehiculeId { get; set; }

        public int CompanyId { get; set; }

        public DateTime LatestRegistrationStatusChangeDate { get; set; }
        //public int RegistrationStatusId { get; set; }

        public bool RegistrationMailSent { get; set; }

        public virtual RegistrationStatus RegistrationStatus { get; set; }


        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }


        public virtual Vehicule Vehicule { get; set; }


        public bool NotAnyFreeLicenceMailSent { get; set; }


        [NotMapped]
        public virtual bool AllowSendNotificationToDevice { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public TrackingState TrackingState { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public ICollection<string> ModifiedProperties { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Guid EntityIdentifier { get; set; }

        partial void AdditionalInit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you do a migration (update)?  You need to do migration to update the database to work with Core 7.  Once the migration is performed, then your old code should work.  There is a mapping between the c# classes and the database.  The mapping is different in Core 7 then 3.1.  Migration only need to be run once.

Comment: I can't modify the database structure. EF Core is used as Database First, not Code First.

Comment: Can you show the entities `Registration` and `Vehicle`?

Comment: You must do a migration.  Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/existing-database

Comment: I'm in a Database First scenario. No migration required.

Comment: @vernou the entities are now shown.

Answer (score 0):

If this is DbFirst, there is a lot of unnecessary noise in the configuration. Things like HasIndex and HasFK only apply to code-first. With DB first you have the  schema set up the way you want, the config only needs to tell EF any variances from convention and relationships. That said, I don't see anything there that should be conflicting with the database, it's just more to read through to get to the relevant details that EF will actually use.

The configuration for the relationship between vehicle and registration is set up for the Registration to be the container for the relationship so in your code example I would use:

```
registration.Vehicule = v;
```

rather than

```
v.Registration = registration;
```

The relationship is mapped from Registration to Vehicle with the FK on Registration and null-ability rule. You could also set both navigation properties and that should work as well.  I'm not sure why that might have worked in EF Core 3.1 and changed in a later version, but that would be something to try.

Also note that if you are creating a registration for an existing vehicle you will need to reference an instance of the vehicle that is tracked by the DBContext to avoid something like a PK constraint error or duplicate data being inserted. (if using Identity columns for PK) Your code example as it stands will only work when creating both a new Vehicle instance and a new Registration. This may be what you intend, but if it can handle creating a new Registration for an existing Vehicle record then you need to either fetch the Vehicle by ID (Safest) or attach a populated instance of a vehicle /w Vehicle ID. (After checking `DbContext.Vehicules.Local` for a tracked reference)